# Finding paths between two given GPS coordinates on Google maps embedded in a Qt widget

Tags: qt, google-maps, qt-mobility

Is this the class that does the trick: http://apidocs.meego.com/1.2-preview/qtmobility/qgeoroutingmanager.html ?

Or there are some other ways of doing the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Simple Routing example of the nokia forum wiki agrees with me: http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Qt_Maps_Examples#SimpleRouting

***EDIT***
All these explanations are w.r.t NOKIA's OVI maps. QtMobility doesn't support Google maps. :(